# Hw to format month in 3 letters in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display date in this formate :

```
1st Jan, 2021
```

Month should displayed in 3 letters instead of full name,Currently I am getting in this format :

```
01 January, 2021
```

I am using the following code for this :

```
{{date('d F, Y', strtotime($bootcamp->event_start))}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{date('jS M, Y', strtotime($bootcamp->event_start))}}
```

use simple date function https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this, is to format date with [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization). To get the format you need, you can do something like this:

```
>>> Carbon\Carbon::parse($bootcamp->event_start)->format('dd M, Y');
=> "1st Jan, 2021"
```

Or you can still use the date() function, but change it to this:

```
date('dd M, Y', strtotime($bootcamp->event_start));
=> "1st Jan, 2021"
```

Answer (score 1):

The format you are describing seems to be:

`jS M, Y`

As we can see in the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp):

```
jS: "7th", "22nd", "31"
M: 'jan' | 'feb' | 'mar' |
Y: "1991", "1992", "1993"
```

So that would be:

`{{date('jS M, Y', strtotime($bootcamp->event_start))}}`